# Heroku requires specific git directory layout - how can I work around that?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a Node.js project that I like to upload to the [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) service. To upload it, it requires me to use a git repository, so that it can push my files to its git server.

Heroku expects to find a `package.json` file (used by Node.js) at the root of the git repository's directory tree.

Now, before I had started trying out Heroku, I had already created my own git repo, which start one parent dir further up. I intend to have not only this node.js project in my single git repo but other related projects as well. I like to avoid splitting up my repo into several separate ones just to make Heroku happy.

Here's my desired layout:

```
main/
  nodejs-project/
    package.json
    ...
  artwork/
    ...
  docs/
    ...
```

I hope you get the idea - I want the entire `main` folder's hierarchy managed by a git repo, but heroku requires the `nodejs-project` subfolder to be its own git repo so that it can find the `package.json` file at its root.

What options to I have to solve this?

Comment: Possibly [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: Never used submodules with git. Before I dive into this, I'd rather have someone tell me with certainty that this is going to work.

Comment: I think it fits your use case, but I'm not myself a Heroku user.  Fortunately, it's the sort of thing you can try non-destructively.  Make a copy of your repository and give it a try.  Don't like it? Wipe the copy and continue on your merry way.

Comment: It will work, but you won't be able to keep all the files within the same repo then. With git submodules you'd essentially split them into several and use .submodule:s to tell git that when you use main repo, you have dependencies to other repos as well. You'd then fetch those others with git submodule update --init or similar.

Comment: Do you intend to use Heroku in a one-off test or permanently? Do you intend to use Heroku for your other projects within the same repo as well?

Comment: I am currently exploring Heroku, later deciding whether to use it permanently. I dislike having to maintain two separate repos for my big project, just because some 3rd party service requires me to due to their limitations. I like to see if Heroku has a solution for this - maybe there's a way to specify to find the relevant files in that subdir and not in the root of the repo, or something like that.

Comment: Maybe I should rather ask: What alternative (and similarly free-for-low-needs) services are there for deploying node.js apps?